# Python Selenium Script:

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I wrote a script to save LinkedIn information like: name, last name, graduated university and most important link to LinkedIn script. My script is using Selenium and chromedriver to enter LinkedIn and then scrape. My problem is with saving profile links. Links aren't scraping properly. Here's my code:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import parameters
import re

class LinkedIn():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.people_ls_dic = []
        self.csv_name_colums = ["name","degree_connection","zawod","region","opis","firma","link"]

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com/login")
        sleep(3)

        username = self.driver.find_element_by_name('session_key')
        username.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_username)

        password = self.driver.find_element_by_name('session_password')
        password.send_keys(parameters.linkedin_password)
        
        sign_in_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn__primary--large from__button--floating mercado-button--primary"]')
        sign_in_button[0].click()
        sleep(5)


    def neville_try(self):
        sleep(3)
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        profiles = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul') 
        profiles = profiles.find_elements_by_css_selector('li')
        profiles = [(i.text, i.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-control-name="entity_result"]').get_attribute('href')) for i in profiles]
        print("\n\n")
        
 
        info_ls = []
        for profile, link in profiles:
            info_ls.append( (profile.split('\n'), link) )


        for iteam, link in info_ls:
            if 'Learn more' in iteam:
                info_ls.remove(iteam)


        print(info_ls)
        info_ls = [(iteam, link) for iteam, link in info_ls if iteam != ['']]

  
        for info, link in info_ls:
            if info[0] == info[1]:
                info.remove(info[1])
            try:
                name = info[0]
                degree_connection = info[2]
                zawod = info[3]
                region = info[4]
                opis = info[5]

                opis_f = opis.replace(","," ")

                list_of_user_data = [name, zawod, opis_f]

                for data in list_of_user_data:
                    
                    try:
                        comp = re.findall('at ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)',data)
                        firma = comp[0]
                        break
                    except:
                        continue

                    if comp == []:
                        firma = "brak_danych"
                self.people_ls_dic.append({"name":name,"degree_connection":degree_connection,"zawod":zawod,"region":region,"opis":opis,"firma":firma,"link":link})
            except:
                pass

            
            
        
    def go_home(self):
        home = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inbug-nav-item"]/a')
        home.click()

 
    def next_page(self):
        sleep(3)
        next_p = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-label="Next"]')
        next_p.click()

    
    def open_people(self):

        self.driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?origin=DISCOVER_FROM_SEARCH_HOME")
        sleep(2)

        search_bar = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="search-global-typeahead__input always-show-placeholder"]')
        search_bar.send_keys(parameters.search_query)
        search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        sleep(3) 

    def filter_company(self):
        cl = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-label="Current company filter. Clicking this button displays all Current company filter options."]')
        cl.click()
        for comp in parameters.list_of_comp:
            text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@placeholder="Add a company"]')
            text.send_keys(comp)
            sleep(1)
            filt = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]')
            sleep(0.2)
            filt.click()
        sleep(1)
        apply = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[1]/nav/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[5]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/div[2]/button[2]')
        apply.click()
        sleep(1)

    
    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()
    
    def write_to_csv(self):
        csv_file = "neville.csv"
        with open(csv_file, 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = self.csv_name_colums)
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in self.people_ls_dic:
                writer.writerow(data)
        


scrypt = LinkedIn()


scrypt.login()

scrypt.open_people()



ls = range(parameters.ilosc_stron)
scrypt.filter_company()
for i in sorted(ls,reverse=True):
    scrypt.neville_try()
    if i == 1:
        break
    scrypt.next_page()
    

scrypt.write_to_csv()
scrypt.close()
```

Ofc I have file with parameters and i looks' like this:

```
linkedin_username = ""
linkedin_password = ""
search_query = 'vcloud director'
list_of_comp = ['Microsoft']
ilosc_stron = 2 //number of pages to click on
```

Comment: Please describe more about "Links aren't scrapping properly." What do you expect for link data and what do you get now?

Comment: i expect something like this:   name, last name, current position, lvl of connection and LINK. What I meant by "links aren't scrapping properly ": only one link (to profile) is saved, and every single person has this one link attached